# Sikuli no clicking on Image in POP UP

Tags: java, sikuli

hi guys i am facing a problem .My script is using sikuli API for image based automation .My problem is i click a button "A" then a pop up appears then i want to click an image B sikuli gets coordinates of B correctly but when it calls click there is null pointer exception shown . I know what is problem but i don't know its solution.Script is not able to click because current focus of sikuli is on previous screen containing button A so it say null pointer exception .Any one knows how to switch focus to active screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding long wait solved my problem :

```
try {
                    driver.wait(2000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: You also could add a `while not exists()`. 
That one will wait until the image appears, and the automaticly go further. 
Then you don't have to wait `2000 seconds` if the image is already visible after `100 seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

To focus on a pop-up you could use:

```
App.focusedWindow()
```